# Google chrome address bar amplified

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

Once I mistakenly hit some keys and the there came up a big address bar, which I think will be helpful for presentations, but I don't what keyboard shortcut it is. Does anyone know? Thanks.

It's very similar to the screenshot in the following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/43571/weird-google-chrome-feature-huge-address-bar-pops-up

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

- Go one this adress with the adress bar

  > chrome://settings/
- Click on **Show advanced settings...**
- And go on the optio **Web Content**
- You can change the **zoom** and **Font size.**

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't already, try disabling any/all extensions you have (specifically the goo.gl shortener extension noted in the ubuntu thread you linked) to see if it goes away.

In case you find it's the goo.gl extension like the other thread, from the extensions page (You can browse to `chrome://extensions/` to see them all), below the goo.gl extension, if you click "Options" next to the check box for allow in incognito, there is a "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab where you can see all assigned shortcuts that might have triggered this pop-up search/address box.